# Storing multiple sizes of multiple images for one database entry

Tags: php, mysql

Assuming the following database entry..

```
ID  Name          Slug
--------------------------
1   My Brand      my-brand
```

..would it be a good idea to store My Brand's logo and/or other images like this?

```
/img/logos/my-brand-50x50.png
/img/logos/my-brand-100x100.png
/img/screenshots/my-brand-800x600.png
```

Current thoughts are:

### PROS

- Eliminates extra database columns/tables.
- Allows for additional sizes to be added at any time in future.

### CONS

- Requires PHP to check that the requested image exists on every request. If so, load it, if not, check for similar sizes, if not, load a default placeholder.

### Options

1. Use `/{image_type}/{slug}-XxY.png` + check for file exists every time.
2. Use `/{image_type}/{slug}-XxY.png` + CSS background-image + set placeholder background on parent element. Ignore 404 on non-existent images, letting placeholder show instead.
3. Use additional database columns.
4. Use a separate images table.

Which is the acceptable way to handle this? Am I missing some other obvious, better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about speed, capacity and scalability.

**Fast solution** (fast for a client) is like you already mentioned: to store separate files for different sizes. The facts are:

- it's fast (because files are existing phisically)
- it's hard to scale (if I need size 404x404 I need to add new image, if I need 1337x1337 I need to add new image again)
- it takes a lot of space to store this all images

**Capacity aware solution** is the opposite. We store one big image for desired proportions and scale it on demand.

For example, we can have only one file: `my-brand-2000x2000.png`. If user (or whatever) needs `my-brand-405x405.png` or `my-brand-1337x1337.png` we can take `my-brand-2000x2000.png`, scale and display it.
The facts are:

- it's quite slow (because we compute image every request)
- it's fully scalable (we can derive 1x1,2x2,3x3,...,2000x2000 images from one 2000x2000 image)
- it takes minimum of space to store this few images

**Ideal solution** is to mix these two presented above. We store one big image for desired proportions and scale it on demand. However, this time we will also try to cache sizes that we scale often.

For example, imagine we have three types of users: lost users that always want to have `my-brand-404x404.png`, elite users that always want to have `my-brand-1337x1337.png` and satanist users that always want to have `my-brand-666x666.png`. We store only `my-brand-2000x2000.png` and scale it to one of three sizes. After few days we look at statistics and we see that for 1000 requests we produced as follows:

- `my-brand-666x666.png` 2 times
- `my-brand-404x404.png` 499 times
- `my-brand-1337x1337.png` 499 times

It is obvious now that we should cache last two and should not cache 666x666.

The facts about solution are:

- it's faster than capacity aware solution due to cache
- it's still as scalable as capicity aware solution
- it consumes less space than fast solution

**Implementation** is not that hard. For example you can use GD in PHP. I recommend to store images not in filesystem but in database. You are then filesystem-independend and also technology-independend. Way to access images may look like: `image.php?brand=my-brand&w=1337&h=1337`. `image.php` should interpret parameters, lookup image in database or cache and if there is no such: scale, update statistics and display.

Here is example of dynamic image, try to change parameter: http://www.cs.put.poznan.pl/adanilecki/create_img.php?text=Hi%20there

Comment: Great answer. Makes perfect sense and made me chuckle, too! Thanks.